# Postgres : Relation does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I used pg_restore to load my postgres db with a dump file.
I connected to my db with my user :

```
sudo -u arajguru psql dump

select current_user;
 current_user 
--------------
 arajguru
```

Now I was able to see all the newly created tables:

```
dump=> \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------------+-------+----------
 public | Approvals         | table | arajguru
 public | Approvers         | table | arajguru
 public | Conditions        | table | arajguru
 public | Entities          | table | arajguru
 public | EntityDefinitions | table | arajguru
 public | Projects          | table | arajguru
 public | Rules             | table | arajguru
 public | run_history       | table | arajguru
(8 rows)
```

But when I try to fire a select * query, it gave me this error:

```
dump=> select * from Approvals;
ERROR:  relation "approvals" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Approvals;
```

What can be the reason for this error? Please help.

Comment: try to rimraf dist

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You created your tables with double quotes, and now the names are case sensitive.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `"Approvals"` and `Approvals` are two different names.

Now that you created the table names in a case sensitive manner, you have to use those dreaded double quotes always.

```
select * 
from "Approvals";
```

---

As a general advice: [never use double quotes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) in SQL.

Comment: Thanks! Working now. How did you know that the tables were created with double quotes?

Comment: @AyushiRajguru: because the "List of tables" shows them with Upper/lowercase. The only way to achieve that is to use double quotes (as  [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS))